# Unexpected end of JSON input while run npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

While installing the `eslint` npm package like this

```
npm i eslint -g
```

I got the below error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."coveralls":"2.11.4",'

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have tried this and it is working fine for me. Can you please share more details that which platform you are using, which version of node you have.

Comment: @LalitKushwah macOS - Node 10.15.3

Comment: can you try npm i eslint -g  --verbose ? For getting detailed logs

Comment: @LalitKushwah I solved it using `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow these below steps:

**Method 1:**

**1.** clean your cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**2.** Then install latest angular cli:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**3.** Then install your package

```
npm install -g eslint
```

**Method 2:**

**1.** Uninstall `nodejs`

**2.** Clear cache by this command: `npm cache clean --force`

**3.** delete `package-lock.json` and node `node_modules` folder

**4.** Install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) latest version

**5.** Install latest angular cli `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.

**6.** Run `npm install`.

**7.** Install your desired package that you wants.

Hope it resolve your issue.If not then please let me know.Generally,In most of the cases method 1 works if method 1 not works go for 2nd method.
Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity: why install latest angular cli?

Comment: It gets better with each version and also the performance, its latest updates have decreased JS bundles size and runtime performance.Updating often include faster build times and quicker Angular apps.

Comment: I mean, dadwic haven't mentioned they use angular in their project, so I didn't get how this is connected to the issue. Is this just updating any package between cleaning cache and installing eslint? Or does angular cli somehow affects the bundle?

Comment: sometimes dependencies affects.So I tried to give the best solution in my known, if it up-to date then it simply skip this otherwise install it.And it's good to update the cli version and keep the packages updated